# Execute shell command in jenkins with quotes

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh

I am trying to execute shell command in Jenkins pipeline but if I type this:

```
 sh aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name Name --version-label v2 --source-bundle S3Bucket=\\"my-bucket\\",S3Key=\\"test.zip\\"
```

All quotes cuts out from string and I get invalid command:

```
...S3Bucket=my-bucket,S3Key=test.zip
```

I found solution but it does't work with injectable variables

```
sh '''
.... --source-bundle S3Bucket=\\"my-bucket\\",S3Key=\\"test.zip\\"

'''
```

I looked through a bunch of information but did not find any solution. Could anyone help me with this?
How can I execute shell command in jenkins with injectable variables and quotes, example:

```
sh 'my awesome command var1="${var1}"'
```

Comment: Just replace single quotes to double eg: change from sh ''' ${var} ''' to sh """ ${var} """

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
 node { 
   stage('Build') {
     S3Bucket='"my-bucket"'
     S3Key='"test.zip"'
     print 'sh aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name Name --version-label v2 --source-bundle S3Bucket='+S3Bucket+',S3Key='+S3Key
   }
  }
```

OUTPUT : sh aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name Name --version-label v2 --source-bundle S3Bucket="my-bucket",S3Key="test.zip"